# Get parent of ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial that has been passed an association. I want to get the object that passed me the association. How do I do this? I thought it would be easy but I cannot seem to find the method.

Here is what I pass to the partial:

```
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/records_table', :locals => {:parent => @location, :records => @location.people} %>
```

Here is what I would like to pass to the partial:

```
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/records_table', :locals => {:records => @location.people} %>
```

There are also instances like this:

```
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/records_table', :locals => {:parent => @time, :records => @time.families} %>
```

And:

```
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/records_table', :locals => {:parent => @car, :records => @car.families} %>
```

I do not know the class of the association or the parent.

Comment: Showing the partial code above. I want to use records to get @location

Answer (score 2):

Ran into something similar and the following worked. The `ActiveRecord::Association` has a method to return the owner.

`@foo.bars.proxy_association.owner` => `@foo`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're opposed to just passing that information into the partial, but if location has many people and person belongs to location, then you can just take any of the people in that partial and call location to get the parent.

edit: Add a `parent` method on your models that returns the appropriate association. For example `person.parent` would return a `Location` object.

Seriously though, there's nothing wrong with just passing the parent into the partial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added another example to show why this would not work. I do not know the type of the association or parent.

Comment: Why are you against passing the parent to the partial?

Comment: Just seems unnecessary and redundant. I am going to use this partial a lot and would prefer not to have to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine in your Location class you have something like `has_many :people`, and your Person class has something like `belongs_to :location`. So why not just alias `#parent` to the parent of each class. Your Person class would then look like:

```
belongs_to :location
alias_method :parent, :location
```

That way all your records will respond to parent and you won't need to pass it in to the partial. You'd need to do something similar in your Family class.

A caveat on this is that calling `parent` in the partial will load the parent from the database *for each record*. When rendering your partial you would need to do something like this to avoid that:

```
render :partial => 'shared/records_table', :locals => {:records => @location.people.includes(:location)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this does not work either. The problem is that all of these models are interrelated. There are multiple parents. I am really looking for owner of the association.